# NSUserDefaults Settings Page Not Saving

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, uislider

I would like to create a settings page, where it sets/gets the slider value (text Size) from NSUserDefaults, but my app is having none of it. I dont get any errors, it just doesn't want to save. I've commented the code, to help you understand better what I want to do, but it's quite simple. I have a 7-stage slider that has the font sizes, and you can simply slide it to determine what size of font you want - that is the value I want saved throughout the app. But whenever I press back on the navigation bar and open the settings page again, the default size is always 22.

.h

```
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sizeSlider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sampleText;

@end
```

.m

```
@interface SettingsViewController () {
    NSArray *numbers;
    NSMutableAttributedString *sampleTextString;
    int fontSize;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
}

@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";

    numbers = @[@(10), @(12), @(14), @(16), @(18), @(20), @(22)];                 // Text Sizes, these number values represent each slider position
    NSInteger numberOfSteps = ((float)[numbers count]-1);                           // Slider values go from 0 to the number of values in your numbers array

    self.sizeSlider.maximumValue = numberOfSteps;                                   // As the slider moves it will continously call the -valueChanged:
    self.sizeSlider.minimumValue = 0;


    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];                                //Setting the font to be the current font saved in the system
    long textsize = [defaults integerForKey:@"fontSize"];
    NSLog(@"textsize: %ld", textsize);
    self.sizeSlider.value = textsize;                                               // Set the Slider to whatever font you had set it previously



    self.sizeSlider.continuous = YES;                                               // NO makes it call only once you let go
    [self.sizeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    sampleTextString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog!"];
    self.sampleText.attributedText = sampleTextString;

    [sampleTextString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:textsize] range:NSMakeRange(0, sampleTextString.length)];

}


-(void)valueChanged:(UISlider *)sender{
    NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(self.sizeSlider.value + 0.5);       // round the slider position to the nearest index of the numbers array
    [self.sizeSlider setValue:index animated:NO];


    NSNumber *number = numbers[index];                                  // <-- This numeric value you want
    [sampleTextString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[number floatValue]] range:NSMakeRange(0, sampleTextString.length)];

    [defaults setInteger:[number integerValue] forKey:@"fontSize"];         // Saving fontSize to NSUserDefaults
    [defaults synchronize];

    self.sampleText.attributedText = sampleTextString;
}
@end
```

Comment: Your code to save the value saves the point size but the code to load the value attempts to set the slider's index to the saved font size. That's not consistent and needs to be fixed.

Comment: I've edited the code to show the change in font size.

Comment: You missed my point. In `viewDidLoad` you call `self.sizeSlider.value = textsize;`. But the slider's value isn't the text size, it's the index into the array of sizes.

Comment: I see, so how would I correspond the slider index to the font size? Would i have to make an array to find which index the font size is?

Comment: Just get the index of the number within the `numbers` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer comes from rmaddy - Thanks!

I needed to look at the index, rather than the actual value of the array.

```
NSInteger indexText = [numbers indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:textsize]];
```

So I put that in, and that returned the index of the slider position I wanted.